# How to play opus audio in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, html5-audio, opus

How can I play opus audio in browsers which are old or not compatible with the audio format.

At the moment I serve the audio link in a html5 `<audio>` tag which works in Firefox and Chrome but it does not in IE, any version.

I have read about opus.js and opusenc.js which is a JavaScript port of the opusenc tool, which in turn is part of the opus-tools collection, created with Emscripten.

Do you know whether is it possible to play opus audio files using any of these JS in incompatible browsers?

Opus browser compatibility [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=opus)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Audio5js](https://github.com/zohararad/audio5js) seems promising

Not sure yet it supports opus codec

From Documentation:

> Audio5js.can_play class method supports the following mime-type
> queries:
>
> mp3 - check for audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3". Example  Audio5js.can_play('mp3')
>
> vorbis - check for audio/ogg;
> codecs="vorbis". Example - Audio5js.can_play('vorbis')
>
> opus - check for audio/ogg; codecs="opus". Example - Audio5js.can_play('opus')
>
> webm - check for audio/webm; codecs="vorbis". Example - Audio5js.can_play('webm')
>
> mp4 - check for audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.5". Example - Audio5js.can_play('mp4')
>
> wav - check for audio/wav; codecs="1". Example - Audio5js.can_play('wav')

This lets me think it can

Comment: Did you ever discover if it did or not?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not have the time to test it myself. Please update this post if you manage to have it working

Comment: This plugin supports opus codec, but it's still just a wrapper around the HTML5 audio element. Does not work in IE per my experience.